# HeidiSQL can't connect to my RDS database?

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, heidisql

Hoping someone can help me with this issue I am running into. HeidiSQL won't connect to my RDS database. I can connect to it when I'm on my EC2 instance but not using Heidi SQL. The error I keep getting is:

> Can't connect to MySQL server on 'localhost' (10061).

Anyone know how to get HeidiSQL to work with RDS on AWS?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! I edited your question to format the error message as a blockquote so that it renders properly and is more readable - please see the editing help for more information on formatting. Please edit in to provide more detail that's necessary to identify the specific problem. Good luck!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand right, RDS just needs an SSH tunnel before connecting per HeidiSQL to its MySQL server. Setting up a SSH tunnelled connection in HeidiSQL is easy, and documented [in the help section](http://www.heidisql.com/help.php#connecting).

There are also examples on how to connect especially to Amazon RDS via HeidiSQL, for example: http://www.arcusglobal.com/news/accessing-rds-using-heidisql

Comment: Just in case anyone stumbles across this and the Arcus Global link above, I had to use the instance Public IPv4 address under the SSH tunnel tab -> SSH input field in order to connect. (the aws endpoint wasn't working for ssh purposes)

Comment: Note that newer HeidiSQL versions have a separate network type "MySQL on RDS", which can be used either with or without SSH tunnel.

Answer (score 17):

Here is how I did it using MySQL(TCP/IP option)

1. On Amazon RDS, set RDS instance to be publicly accessible. 
   Go to Details -> Modify -> Network & Security -> Public accessibility
   -> Yes
2. Modify Security Group to allow access to your IP.

   RDS Instance page -> Connect -> Security group rules -> Select Security Group -> Inbound ->Edit -> Add Rule -> Type = MYSQL/Aurora -> Protocol = TCP -> Port range =3306 -> Source = My IP -> Save
3. On HeidiSql,

   ```
   New Session -> 

    Setting tab ->

       Network Type = MySQL (TCP/IP)
          Hostname/IP = your RDS instance endpoint
          User = RDS instance username
          Password = your password
          Port = 3306
          Compressed client/server protocol = yest
          Databases = your database name
   ```

   Hit Open

Instructions used from [Connecting to a DB Instance Running the MySQL Database Engine](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/USER_ConnectToInstance.html)

HeidiSQL has issues connecting via SSL using the certificate issued by AWS. I used Eclipse and its plugins for SSL connection.

Comment: This is what I was looking for.

Comment: After modifying the security group I had to wait ~10 minutes until the change was in effect.

Answer (score 0):

This detailed instructions worked for me: [Connect To Amazon RDS (Or Any Database) Using HeidiSQL Via SSH Tunneling](https://ehikioya.com/amazon-rds-heidisql-ssh-tunneling/)